# Simulating random walkers which can not collide into each other in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, collision-detection, simulation

I have written a code to simulate the motion of circular particles in a 2d box. Whenever they move out of the box, I put them inside the box and near the wall. I want to add the diameter (2R) of particles in the code, which means when the distance between the center of two circles become less than 2R, they separate along the line connecting their centers so that the distance between the centers of the circles becomes equal to 2R.

Could anyone suggest a code to perevent the overlapping of particles?

This is my code in which overlap is not considered:

```
clear all
close all
l = 224; nn = 800; %number of particles
time = 1000; dd = 1;
x= l*rand(1,nn);
y= l*rand(1,nn);

for t = 1:time;
x= x + rand(1,nn)-0.5* ones(1,nn);
y=y+rand(1,nn)-0.5* ones (1,nn);
index = (x < 0); x(index) = abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
index = (y < 0); y(index) = abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
index = (x > l); x(index) = l-abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
index = (y > l); y(index) = l-abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
end
```

Comment: So each particle travels in a straight line until it makes contact with a wall, when it "bounces off", and you want to also include particle-on-particle collisions?

Comment: No direction and length step of each step changes during passing the time (I have used random number to do that).Yes when the distance between the center of two circles become less than 2R, they separate along the line connecting their centers and distance of centers of circle become equal to  @Wolfie

Comment: Could you help please? @Wolfie

Comment: What happens in the (perhaps unlikely) event that 3 or more particles collide at once?

Comment: If 3 particles collide, again the distance between each two of particles becomes equal 2R. If it is still unclear, please let me knw@Wolfie

Comment: The problem you're looking at is called [Collision Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some commented code which does what you want. Notably:

- `psize` is some defined particle size for interaction.
- point-to-point distances found using `pdist2`.
- points that are too close are moved away from each other by some amount (`dp` times their current distances, if `dp=1/2` then their x and y distances double) until there are no clashes.

See comments for details.

```
clear; close all;
l = 224; nn = 800; % number of particles
time = 100;
x = l*rand(1,nn); y = l*rand(1,nn);
psize = 2;         % Particle size for interaction
dp = 0.1;

figure; hold on; axis([0 l 0 l]);
for t = 1:time;
    % Random movement
    movement = 2*rand(2,nn)-1;
    x = x + movement(1,:);
    y = y + movement(2,:);
    index = (x < 0); x(index) = abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
    index = (y < 0); y(index) = abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
    index = (x > l); x(index) = l-abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));
    index = (y > l); y(index) = l-abs(normrnd(0,1,1,nnz(index)));

    % Particle interaction. Loop until there are no clashes. For
    % robustness, some max iteration counter should be added!
    numclash = 1;
    while numclash > 0
        dists = pdist2([x;y]', [x;y]');   % Distances between all particles
        dists(dists < psize) = NaN;       % Those too close are assigned NaN
        tooclose = isnan(tril(dists,-1)); % All NaNs identified by logical
        [clash1,clash2] = find(tooclose); % Get particles which are clashing
        numclash = numel(clash1);         % Get number of clashes
        % All points where there was a clash, move away from each other
        x(clash1) = x(clash1) + (x(clash1)-x(clash2))*dp;
        x(clash2) = x(clash2) - (x(clash1)-x(clash2))*dp;
        y(clash1) = y(clash1) + (y(clash1)-y(clash2))*dp;
        y(clash2) = y(clash2) - (y(clash1)-y(clash2))*dp;
    end

    % Plot to visualise results. Colour fade from dark to bright green over time
    scatter(x,y,'.','markeredgecolor',[0.1,t/time,0.4]);
    drawnow;
end
hold off
```

Result:

[image: random walk]

---

Edit:

For a clearer diagram, you could initialise some colour matrix `C = rand(nn,3);` and plot using

```
scatter(x,y,[],C*(t/time),'.'); % the (t/time) factor makes it fade from dark to light
```

This would give each particle a different colour, which also fade from dark to light, rather than just fading from dark to light as before. The result would be something like this:

[image: colours]

Comment: I can not underestand difference between clash1 and clash2

Comment: Each particle in `clash1` collides with the corresponding particle in `clash2`. I don't know, please provide an example, perhaps with the particles as circles of the correct size so you can clearly see if they are actually colliding. If this answer works, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Does the code works properly when 5 or 8 particles collide togheter?

Comment: I haven't fully tested this code, but the way it works (as stated) is to keep moving the particles apart until there are no overlaps before moving onto the next iteration, so yes it should work. It may look like it doesn't because of the large number of particles you are using, the large size of grid, and the fact that the scatter points' size in no way matches your defined point size `psize`

Comment: I didn't do that because there is an issue in the code: consider a case in which a mass of particles is created. In this case, it's better that particles go far from each other from the mass but it is not considered in the code. Am I correct?

Comment: You can test with the above code, initialising `x = (l/2)+rand(1,nn); y = (l/2)+rand(1,nn);` (so entire mass of 800 particles is within **one unit** of each other in the center) and `dp=1` for speed, then they all initially spread out until they have sufficient distance and then iterate. I don't know what you think isn't considered?

Comment: I mean the case they are uniformly and compactly spread in a circle, not at one point

Comment: Niche cases included, these points will always just move away from all neighbours which they are too close to, until they aren't too close, no matter the configuration. If that is what you want, please mark the question as closed. If it isn't what you want, please edit your question to include extra specifications which this doesn't satisfy.